# Is listening to location changes saves the position of the device to the cache?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using

> xam.plugin.geolocator

to get the location of my device I just want to clarify something.

```
await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), defaultgpsaccuracy, false, new Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ListenerSettings
{
    ActivityType = Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ActivityType.Other,
    AllowBackgroundUpdates = true,
    DeferLocationUpdates = true,
    DeferralDistanceMeters = 1,
    DeferralTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
    ListenForSignificantChanges = true,
    PauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
});
```

I am using this code to listen for position changes.

I want to clarify two things:

1. is the position captured my the listening function stored in the location cache?
2. When I use **GetLastKnownLocationAsync()** function does the position returned by this is the location that the listening function captured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Source**](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/CurrentLocation.html)

**(1)** Yes, the location will be stored in cache, quoting the documentation:

> **Cached/Last Known Location**: Before querying for a full location which
>   will boot up sensors for geolocation you can query for the last known
>   or cached location of the manager. It will return null if no cached
>   location is available.

Gets the last known and most accurate location.

This is usually cached and best to display first before querying for full position.
returns **Best** and **most recent** location or null if none found

```
Task< Position > GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
```

This quote also answers the question nº2

**(2)** Yes, it returns the **last** captured location.

Comment: is there a better way to improve this? In order to get the gps position faster and accurately?

Comment: @MaricrisPacheco I'm guessing you need to be listening constantly to the user location by what i have seen in your example, but that doesn't change (imo) the flow of it, 1st- you should check if theres any LastKnownLocation, to be able to show the user location right away (even if its not the most acurate), this behaviour can be seen on google maps, if you traveled by car and the last time you turn on the mobile data was in your house, google maps takes a few seconds before showing the actual location, but shows that you are in your house first.

Comment: 2nd - depending on the level of accuracy you are loking for, you should query the location in the background without interrupting the UI (because this query takes sometime) and update it once you got it, and then you should start listening for changes

Comment: 3rd - By the params you passed in the example, you really need to be accurate with the location, if you are trying to do something with veichles, that "might" be the way to go, i have never done that so i dont know what is the best way to do it, but if your app if for users while walking or something like that, you can reduce a little the amount of times you get a location back, and try to see if the location you cathed difers (like 10m or so) from the previous location, so you dont have to updated everytime, you can use google maps example again, if you are walking and have directions on

Comment: you can see that your location is not "smooth", it jumps from time to time.